# java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling

Tags: jsp, struts, rmi

I get this execption when I try to access the RMI serevr from action class of struts(i.e. RMI client) (on the click of the jsp button)

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:    
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mindcraft.queryExecutor.actionclass.ExecutorInterface (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

Below is my RMI client snippet

```
try{   
        ExecutorInterface p=(ExecutorInterface)Naming.lookup("//localhost:2007/exec1");   
        System.out.println("Inside client.."+ p.toString());   
        int a= p.getJobStatus("2");   
        System.out.println("a..." + a);   
        p.killJob("1");   
            p.executeJob(id, usrname, pswd);   
        System.out.println("Threads started, main ends\n");   
        }   
        catch(Exception e)   
        {   
            System.out.println("Execption in RMI..."+ e);   
            e.printStackTrace();   
        }
```

It was fine when I try above code in separate file with public static void main(),but gets above exception when tried the same code in Action class of struts framework.

Comment: This has something to do with the policy file.

Comment: which file java.policy or java.security file???

Comment: a policy file for the java security file :D

Comment: @Th0rndike This has nothing to do with the policy file. The exceptions says there is no security manager, ergo there is no policy file in effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this around:

Set a security policy file such as:

```
grant {  
permission java.security.AllPermission "", "";  
};
```

In your start up commands:

```
-Djava.security.policy=/Security/policy.all
```

source: [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/459111/java/java/no-security-manager-rmi-class)

try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: The link you cited concerns `AccessControlException`, not `ClassNotFoundException`. What this solution does is *provide* a security manager and enforce that policy file. He may not need a security manager at all.

Comment: @EJP mind explaining further? i'm no expert in this area, just lucky to find a solution. But i am interested in understanding the problem.

Comment: If he was trying to use to codebase feature and didn't have a security manager, specifying a policy file turns on the security manager, which turns on the codebase feature. If he wasn't trying to use the codebase feature, this is not a solution: the solution is to deploy the missing class to the client.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to take care of the below to avoid this error:

1. You have to make sure the interface name in server are same with interface implement in the client.
2. Make Sure the package name, the place where you put the interface in the client are the same with the package name you put interface in the server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in the validation in the new Java 7 and Java 6 versions.
**Bug id is : 6861062   java    classes_security    Disable MD2 in certificate chain validation**.

When signing the Jara file , I had some warning message and when executing the command:
jarsigner MyTools.jar -verify -verbose -certs

I had the message:
      X.509, OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 29.01.96 01:00 to 02.08.28 01:59]
      [CertPath not validated: Algorithm constraints check failed: MD2withRSA]

My solution is :
- use another version of the JDK to sign and JRE Plugin.
- Update your certificate security in order not to use this algorithm.